# How to pass the query string used to access a page in a link in a views content pane?

Tags: 7, views, panels

**On a views content pane that shows a list of taxonomy terms, is there any way to simply rewrite all the term links such that the query string in the URL with which the page was accessed is appended?**

I'm using Drupal 7 with Views 3 and Panels 3. I have a views content pane displayed in Panels shows a list of countries.  Clicking a country goes to the country's term page (countries are taxonomy terms), which shows all of the users registered in that country (again via Panels overriding the taxonomy term pages).  These term pages (also made with views and contextual filters) accept query strings for exposed filters such as `?friendship=1'.

What I would like to do is link to the location-based search from other pages on the site and pass values to the term page view via the query string.  However, since I don't know what country the user will want to search, I have to link to the Panel that shows the list of countries.  However, since the views content pane displayed in this panel shows terms by aggregation, the query string is not passed when a user clicks one of the links.

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. It's a shame I've missed this for almost a year. :( Are you still interested in this? Getting Panels to pass the information to Views shouldn't be terribly hard, possibly it would require a new context, but I could whip up a sandbox project to solve that part if necessary. I'm not quite sure about having Views accept the argument though, I don't think I understand how you've implemented the View. For better or (mostly) worse, the query string should be automatically available to the View, even as a content pane, so that should "just work". Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you need to tell views to pass the url path to the content pane (views > pane settings > use panel path).

Comment: Footnote: If you need to pass a contextual filter argument, that's at views > pane settings > argument input > from panel argument. To set that argument, have an entry something available in page manager > settings > basic > path (e.g. term/!tid).

Comment: You also might be able to pass the argument via a context (page manager > settings > arguments, assign the argument to taxonomy term: ID). That set, you'd go to views and use the "from context" argument input (Taxonomy Term: Term ID as the required context).